# Unable to change background color of Navbar bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been searching all over for a solution. I am trying to change the background color of my navbar but it will not change color. My CSS link is after the bootstrap CSS cdn  (common suggestion). When i add all my code to jsfiddle it changes without issue but when viewing my page in Chrome it doesn't (won't let me post a third link but trust me its grey not red). The weird part is that when i inspect the page in chrome the default background is struck through ([http://imgur.com/qEZqQAg](https://imgur.com/qEZqQAg)) and my code is active ([http://imgur.com/zuc0yRq](https://imgur.com/zuc0yRq)) but it still doesn't change.

Full HTML Navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- 
   expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
    <img src="newburyvision/meetstaff/eye.jpg" class="navbar-brand"/>
     <a href="#" class="navbar-text navbar-left">
      <h1> Eye Glass Company</h1>
       <h4>eye exams, contacts lenses and fashionable eyewear</h4>
     </a>
</div> <!--End Navbar header-->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-
1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Meet Our Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Book an Appointment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Directions + Hours</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!--End Navbar Collapse-->
</div>  <!--End Container-->
</nav>
```

Full CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
    height: 80px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-top: 4%;
}


.navbar-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar-text h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.navbar-text h4 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i finally figured out what was happening. A background image was blocking my background color. I just sat in the google inspect and turned off every css i could find. Anyways the code i put was to fix it

**CSS**

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: red !important;
  background-image: none;
}
```

I dont really think the !important is necessary because as someone stated above, it isn't an override issue

**Screenshots of the particular background image that was giving me
   issues**

Clicked on and blocking my background color

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk3bt.jpg

Clicked off and background color (finally) showing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBgWu.jpg

Comment: I did not add the background image. All code in my project (its just the navbar right now) was shared in my original post. I believe the background image was a default addition through the class i used (bootstrap 3 class). And agreed since its not an override issue i do not need the important, will remove.